# Подмена value на галочки в таблице

Tags: checkbox, php

Доброго времени суток.

На сайте есть форма. Человек там заполняет поля и выбирает варианты (чекбоксы). После этого форма отправляется в скрипт, который пишет данные в файл "basa_table.txt". Затем на этой же странице заполняется таблица с этими данными, которые подгружаются из файла "basa_table.txt". Код можно посмотреть ниже:

**index.php**

```
<html>
<title>Участники</title>

<head>
<style type="text/css">
#table-members { width:600px; border-collapse:collapse; }
#td, th { padding:5px; border:1px solid black; }

.table-name { background:#00BDEF; font-size:12px; font-weight:bold; color:white; text-transform:uppercase; text-align:left; font-family:"Proxima Nova Semibold",'Helvetica Neue',Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; }
.table-name-2 { width:300px; background:#D1D9DA; font-size:12px; font-weight:bold; color:black; text-transform:uppercase; text-align:left; font-family:"Proxima Nova Semibold",'Helvetica Neue',Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; }
.table-text { background:#D1D9DA; font-size:12px; font-weight:bold; color:black; text-transform:uppercase; text-align:center; font-family:"Proxima Nova Semibold",'Helvetica Neue',Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; }
.table-text-2 { background:#F1F4F5; font-size:12px; color:black; text-transform:uppercase; text-align:center; font-family:"Proxima Nova Semibold",'Helvetica Neue',Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; }
</style>
</head>

<body>
<form id="message" method="post" action="post.php" name="sentPrjForm">
Фамилия:<br />
<input type="hidden" name="myfname" size="50" value="Фамилия" />
<input type="text" name="myfname" class="required validate-alpha" maxlength="100" size="50" />
<br /><br />
Имя :<br />
<input type="hidden" name="mylname" size="50" value="Имя" />
<input type="text" name="mylname" class="required validate-alpha" maxlength="100" size="50" />
<br /><br />
E-mail:<br />
<input type="hidden" name="mymail" value="E-mail" />
<input type="text" name="mymail" class="required validate-email" maxlength="100" size="50" />
<br /><br />

<input type="checkbox" name="option[]" onclick="Calculator.onSelect(1, 100, this)" value="Вариант 01" />Вариант 01<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="option[]" onclick="Calculator.onSelect(1, 100, this)" value="Вариант 02" />Вариант 02<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="option[]" onclick="Calculator.onSelect(1, 100, this)" value="Вариант 03" />Вариант 03<br />

<input type="submit" value="Продолжить" />
</form>

<br /><hr><br />

<b>01</b> - Вариант 01<br />
<b>02</b> - Вариант 02<br />
<b>03</b> - Вариант 03<br />
<br /><br />

<table id="table-members">
<tr><td class="table-name" colspan="7">Список</td></tr>
<tr>
<td class="table-text">№</td>
<td class="table-text">Фамилия</td>
<td class="table-text">Имя</td>
<td class="table-text">E-mail</td>
<td class="table-text">01</td>
<td class="table-text">02</td>
<td class="table-text">03</td>
</tr>

<?php
# Путь к файлу
$file_name = "basa_table.txt";

# Считываем информацию по строкам
$data = file( $file_name );

$i = 1;

# В цикле обходим массив данных
foreach( $data as $value ):

# Разбиваем строку по |
$value = explode( "|", $value );
{
echo '<td class="table-text-2">' . $i++ . '</td>';
echo '<td class="table-text-2">' . $value[0] . '</td>';
echo '<td class="table-text-2">' . $value[1] . '</td>';
echo '<td class="table-text-2">' . $value[2] . '</td>';
echo '<td class="table-text-2"> + </td>';
echo '<td class="table-text-2"></td>';
echo '<td class="table-text-2"> + </td>';
echo '</tr>';
}
?>
<?php
endforeach;
?>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

**post.php**

```
<?php

$project=$_POST['option'];
$myfname=$_POST['myfname'];
$mylname=$_POST['mylname'];
$mymail=$_POST['mymail'];

$handle = fopen("basa_table.txt", "a+");
foreach($project as $option)
{
$opt2 .="- ". $option."<br>";
}

fwrite($handle, $myfname."|");
fwrite($handle, $mylname."|");
fwrite($handle, $mymail."|");
fwrite($handle, $opt2."\r\n");

$URL="/test/";
header ("Location: $URL");

fclose($handle);

?>
```

Задача:

Нужно, чтобы выбранные человеком чекбоксы выводились в таблице в виде галочки, каждый вариант в своем столбце. Не понимаю, как это можно сделать. Изменять атрибуты формы возможности нет - они уже используются для формирования другого текстового файла.

Заранее благодарю за помощь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте сохранять в файл все значения вариантов: 1 - отмечен галочкой, 0 - не отмечен.

```
<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>
function submCheck(){
elem = document.createElement('input');
elem.name = 'sendProject';
elem.value = '';
elem.setAttribute('type','hidden');
elem.type = 'hidden';
for (var i=0;i<3;i++) {
    if (document.getElementsByName('option[]')[i].checked) {
        elem.value = elem.value + '1:';
    }else{
        elem.value =elem.value + '0:';
    }
}
document.getElementsByName('sentPrjForm')[0].appendChild(elem);
document.getElementsByName('sentPrjForm')[0].submit();
return true;
}  
</script>

...

<form id="message" method="post" action="post.php" name="sentPrjForm" onsubmit='return submCheck();'>

...
echo '<table id="table-members">';
echo '<tr><td class="table-name" colspan="7">Список</td></tr>';
echo '<tr>';
echo '<td class="table-text">№</td>';
echo '<td class="table-text">Фамилия</td>';
echo '<td class="table-text">Имя</td>';
echo '<td class="table-text">E-mail</td>';
echo '<td class="table-text">01</td>';
echo '<td class="table-text">02</td>';
echo '<td class="table-text">03</td>';
echo '</tr>';
// В цикле обходим массив данных
foreach( $data as $value ):

//Разбиваем строку по |
$value = explode( "|", $value );

$opt_check = explode(":",$value[3]);
{

echo '<tr><td class="table-text-2">' . $i++ . '</td>';
echo '<td class="table-text-2">' . $value[0] . '</td>';
echo '<td class="table-text-2">' . $value[1] . '</td>';
echo '<td class="table-text-2">' . $value[2] . '</td>';
echo '<td class="table-text-2"> '.checkIns($opt_check[0],1,'+').' </td>';
echo '<td class="table-text-2"> '.checkIns($opt_check[1],1,'+').'</td>';
echo '<td class="table-text-2"> '.checkIns($opt_check[2],1,'+').' </td>';
echo '</tr>';
}
endforeach;
```

и в post.php

```
$opt2 = $_POST['sendProject'];

$URL=$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
```

Comment: Скрипт работает частично - в файл теперь сохраняются значения чекбоксов. При коде ниже значения выводятся в таблицу:
    
    echo '<td class="table-text-2">' . $opt_check[0] . '</td>';
    echo '<td class="table-text-2">' . $opt_check[1] . '</td>';
    echo '<td class="table-text-2">' . $opt_check[2] . '</td>';
    
Но если использовать ваш вариант вывода, то не выводится вообще ничего. А хотелось бы, чтобы значения "1" и "0" заменялись на "+" и "пустое поле" соответственно.

И информации про "checkIns()" не могу найти.

Comment: В JS значения "1" и "0" заменил на "+" и "пустое поле" соответственно. Спасибо за внимание.

Comment: `
function checkIns($val1,$val2,$output = '+'){
return ($val1==$val2>?$output:&nbsp;
}
`

пардон, забыл вписать